# COM object output saved to variable in PowerShell cannot be reused after first access

Tags: powershell, enumerator, comobject

I have a question regarding COM object output saved to a variable in PowerShell:

```
$netShare = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare

$connections = $netShare.EnumEveryConnection
$connectionsProps = $connections | ForEach-Object { $netShare.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_) }
```

After accessing the variable `$connections` once, the variable content is cleared and you cannot reuse it later in a script. While easy to workaround, why is this happening and can you prevent it?

Comment: The likeliest explanation is that `$netShare.EnumEveryConnection` is not a collection, it's [an _enumerator_ object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerator?view=net-8.0#remarks). You can observe the same behavior by assigning an enumerator over an existing collection to a variable: `$enumerator = @(1,2,3,4,5,6).GetEnumerator()`. `$enumerator |ForEach-Object { $_ }` will only work once, since by the end of the loop it's reached the end of the underlying collection - it's _spent_.

Comment: To add to Mathias' comment: If you want to _collect the enumerated objects_ that an enumerator provides (once) , enclose it in `@(...)`, which returns an `[object[]]` array of the enumerated objects: `$connections = @($netShare.EnumEveryConnection)` - see the linked duplicate for details (there, an _explicit_ `.GetEnumerator()` call is used, but the information applies equally).